# Effective method to sort list in Java

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java and am learning collections. I have written the following code to sort the elements in lists.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

class descendingOrder implements Comparator<Integer>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer numberOne, Integer numberTwo) {
        return -numberOne.compareTo(numberTwo); 
    }
}

public class SortsTests {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> listOne = new ArrayList<>();
        listOne.add(1);
        listOne.add(5);
        listOne.add(10);
        listOne.add(6);
        System.out.println(listOne);
        Collections.sort(listOne, new descendingOrder());
        System.out.println(listOne);
    }
}
```

Is this the most effective way to sort the lists or are there any better methods?

Comment: You are only need to implement the `Comparator` when you need to compare object. [To compare integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5894842/4039840), don't need that.

Comment: Don't use unary minus operator to reverse order, because it will fail if `compareTo` returns `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. To reverse order, flip the "arguments", i.e. change `numberOne.compareTo(numberTwo)` to `numberTwo.compareTo(numberOne)`.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "effective".  I can think of possible interpretations (i.e. different meanings that you have in >>your<< head) for which the answers to this question would be "yes", "no", "maybe" or "this question makes no sense".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252269/how-to-sort-a-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: And of course "duplicate question" may also be the answer ... depending on that you mean by the question!

Answer (score 2):

There is already a reverse order `Comparator` built-in to Java. You could also use `Arrays.asList(T...)`; like,

```
List<Integer> listOne = Arrays.asList((Integer) 1, 5, 10, 6);
System.out.println(listOne);
Collections.sort(listOne, Comparator.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(listOne);
```

And if you're using Java 8+, you could do the same with a `Stream` on one line (assuming you don't need to preserve the reverse sorted `List`) like

```
System.out.println(IntStream.of(1, 5, 10, 6).boxed().sorted(Comparator
            .reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```